# Clarification on ROS's port usage

Tags: ros, multi-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to this page: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup, for nodes on two computers to communicate, **all** ports must be open.

1. Doesn't this raise security concerns?
2. Is it really all ports?  Isn't it only ports above 1024 or perhaps a smaller subset?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9725/clarification-on-ros%27s-port-usage/) by [baxelrod](https://answers.ros.org/users/86/baxelrod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 794 on 2011-04-13

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS clients typically bind to port 0.  This will generally return socket port numbers > 1024.  On a default Ubuntu installation, for example, you need superuser to bind <= 1024.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually, an ephemeral port will be used.  The exact range of which can vary by OS and kernel.  See for more info: http://www.ncftp.com/ncftpd/doc/misc/ephemeral_ports.html

---

Originally posted by [baxelrod](https://answers.ros.org/users/86/baxelrod/) with karma: 794 on 2011-05-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1